# I am try to craete survey using JavaScript file and having issue to calculate the total score and %?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a survey. I have already created radio buttons and showing the result of the selected radio button. But I also need to calculate the total score of these radio button values and %. Like if I selected radio value 2 from question 1 and 3 from question 2 the score should be 2+3=5 and % should be 5/6*100 =83.33%

```js
  function displayRadioValue() { 
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
            var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
              
            for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
                  
                if(ele[i].type="radio") { 
                  
                    if(ele[i].checked) 
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML 
                                += ele[i].name + " Value: " 
                                + ele[i].value + "<br>"; 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

```html
 <p> 
        Select a radio button and click on Submit. 
    </p> 
      
    question 1: 
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1 
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2 
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3 
      
    <br> 
      
    question 2: 
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1 
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3
      
    <br> 
      
    <button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
        Submit 
    </button> 
      
    <br> 
      
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Do not confuse JS which runs in EJS (between `<%...%>`) and client-side JS (in `<script>` )

Comment: @Quentin , I dont see where the OP is trying to use EJS here, it's just pure JS.

Comment: @KarlL — See the question’s edit history.

Comment: @Quentin,right is that the reason for the downvote as well you think?

Comment: @KarlL — More likely the lack of research. Adding up some numbers is a pretty trivial task. While there are ways to get it wrong, there’s no sign of an attempt here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function displayRadioValue() {

  var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  let total = 0
  let res = ''
  let totalNumQuestions = 0
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {

    if (ele[i].type = "radio") {

      if (ele[i].checked) {
        totalNumQuestions++
        total += parseFloat(ele[i].value)

        res += ele[i].name + " Value: " + ele[i].value + "<br>";
      }
    }



  }
  res += "Total: " + total + "<br>"
  res += "Percentage: " + ((total / (totalNumQuestions * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res
}
```

```html
<p>
  Select a radio button and click on Submit.
</p>

question 1:
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3

<br>

question 2:
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3

<br>

<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
  Submit
</button>

<br>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: For me your answer is work like a charm.Thanks Karl L

Comment: @jugal like a modal or an alert?

Comment: I want to get the result as a model

Comment: @jugal, sure i have written a quick fiddle for you here https://jsfiddle.net/z7unkfh2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220016/discussion-between-jugal-and-karl-l).